# Format class of many variables at once in R

Tags: r

I have several variables whose names all start with the same pattern in my data frame (around 20). R reads them in as characters but they should be formatted as factors.

Below I have provided a comparable (just much smaller) data frame.

```
animal.farm <- data.frame(matrix(0, 5, 0))
set.seed(1)
animal.farm$ord.3 <- sample(1:4, 5, replace=T)
animal.farm$ani.4 <- sample(c("dog", "horse", "mink"), 5, replace=T)
animal.farm$ani.5 <- sample(c("fun", "boring", "clever"), 5, replace=T)
```

I've tried both

```
ls(pattern = "animal.farm$ani")
```

and

```
apropos("animal.farm$ani")
```

so that I can apply `factor()` to all the variables with one or two lines of code (that in this case start with "ani") but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple base R solution:

```
id <- grep("^ani", names(animal.farm))
animal.farm[id] <- lapply(animal.farm[id], as.factor)
```

Comment: It worked fine with only "ani", how is "^ani" different?

Comment: `^` dtermines the start of the string. Only `"ani"` would have matched each occurence even if it would be at the end or the middle of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr` to detect column names that start with `ani`

```
library(stringr)
cols <- str_detect(colnames(animal.farm), "^ani")
animal.farm[,cols] <- lapply(animal.farm[,cols], as.factor)
```

Comment: Nice, but I guess there is no reason to use packages when a base R solution exists.